# R Shiny: mathematical symbols in plots

Tags: r, shiny

Mathematical annotations in plot labels are not rendered in shiny apps.
Both with base graphics and ggplot2.

Here is a minimal example using both a plotmath expression and a UTF-8 character.
Printing the plots interactively in R or saving through a graphics device such as `png()` renders the symbols correctly.
However, in the shiny app below the symbols are simply not rendered.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, plotOutput("figure1", height = "300px")), 
    column(4, plotOutput("figure2", height = "300px")), 
    column(4, plotOutput("figure3", height = "300px"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$figure1 <- renderPlot(
    plot(1, xlab = "beta")
  )
  output$figure2 <- renderPlot(
    plot(1, xlab = expression(beta))
  )
  output$figure3 <- renderPlot(
    plot(1, xlab = "")
  )
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

[image: shiny does not render mathematical symbols]

Session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.6.0    devtools_2.4.1 usethis_2.0.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        compiler_4.1.0    bslib_0.2.5.1     later_1.2.0       jquerylib_0.1.4   prettyunits_1.1.1 remotes_2.3.0     tools_4.1.0      
 [9] testthat_3.0.2    digest_0.6.27     pkgbuild_1.2.0    pkgload_1.2.1     jsonlite_1.7.2    memoise_2.0.0     lifecycle_1.0.0   rlang_0.4.11     
[17] cli_2.5.0         parallel_4.1.0    fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.4.2       desc_1.3.0        fs_1.5.0          sass_0.4.0        rprojroot_2.0.2  
[25] glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0          processx_3.5.2    bspm_0.3.7        sessioninfo_1.1.1 callr_3.7.0       purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1   
[33] ps_1.6.0          promises_1.2.0.1  ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.1.1 mime_0.10         xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.6.1      cachem_1.0.5     
[41] crayon_1.4.1      Cairo_1.5-12.2
```

Comment: It works for me. I'm using R version 4.1.0 and shiny version 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks for your report. I'm using R v4.0.5 and shiny v1.5.0. Will upgrade and report whether it fixes the issue.

Comment: Your `expression(beta)` in figure2 works for me, but not the direct statement in figure3.

Comment: Upgraded to R v4.1.0 and shiny v1.6.0 on Linux Mint 20.1 (derived from Ubunty 20.04) and the behaviour is still the same as in the reported example (missing symbols). Undergoing upgrade of all other packages to check.

Comment: After upgrading all packages, the problem persists. Added current session info to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting

```r
options(shiny.usecairo = FALSE)
```

which disables graphical rendering by the Cairo package, if it is installed. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.0/shiny-options.html